# Plotting multiple graph series as "stacked" separate graphs

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

Is it possible to have jqPlot render multiple series as a stack of graphs, i.e., each series shares the same x-axis, but each series is not overlaid on top of each other, but underneath each other. Excuse the ASCII art, but something like this:

```
       Item  Item  Item  Item  Item  Item  Item
 ----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 39  |
     |
 38  |                   Series 1
     |
 37  |
 ----+------------------------------------------
 200 |
     |
 180 |                   Series 2
     |
 160 |
 ----+------------------------------------------
   7 |
     |
   6 |                   Series 3
     |
   5 |
```

Moving the x-axis to the top has been straight forward (using x2axis), but stacking the graphs doesn't seem possible.

From what I can tell, there's no obvious way to do this: I could draw three separate graphs and rely on CSS to smash them together to remove whitespace, hoping that jqPlot does render the X-axis the same for each graph (which it should, but as each graph is independent this isn't guaranteed). Or it would be a case of writing a custom renderer for jqPlot?

Just to pre-empt the suggestion: making use of y2axis isn't an option. The charts have some fairly rigid governance around how the information is presented, and it won't be possible to change this.